# Review queue red circle next to triage

Tags: support

I'm having a red dot show up next to the triage queue even though there's nothing in there to do. What does it mean? I don't know where to look to find this out

[image]

Comment: Doesn't really explain why I don't have anything if it's at the threshold...

Comment: There are 68 Triage tasks currently being reviewed, which means there are 68 Triage tasks that are not yet completed but can't be assigned. This is a little bit high - I guess lots of folks jump into review first thing Monday morning.

Comment: bit weird but thanks tho